# aws_launch_configuration: "couldn't find resource" on terraform apply

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm new to Terraform. I've tried everything I know to try. Google has not been helpful in this case.

I'm building a complex cloud infrastructure using Terraform. This includes an auto-scaled ECS service. In order to version-control, document and simplify the modification of this infrastructure, I chose to use Terraform.

I'm at 2 things to create from very, very many more things to create, and I've overcome many problems and learned a lot.

However, there's one problem I can't overcome:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs" {
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.ecs, aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs, aws_key_pair.production]
  name_prefix                 = "${var.ecs_cluster_name}-cluster-"
  image_id                    = lookup(var.amis, "us-east-2")
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  security_groups             = [aws_security_group.ecs.id]
  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.name
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.production.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data                   = "#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER='${var.ecs_cluster_name}-cluster' > /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
  provider = aws.us-east-2

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Planning and applying this results in:

```
│ Error: couldn't find resource
│
│   with aws_launch_configuration.ecs,
│   on 08_ecs.tf line 6, in resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs":
│    6: resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs" {
│
```

What does this mean? What does it mean that the resource isn't found?

It's not the first time I've encountered this error message, but I've previously been able to solve it somehow. In this particular case, I'm at a loss, because nothing I've tried works.

Things I've tried:

- Specifying `depends_on`
- Consulted the Terraform docs on `aws_launch_configuration`
- Googling the error message (no results related to this exact situation)

Seems like I'm the first to have this problem to me.

Version:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\my-project\terraform> terraform version
Terraform v1.2.1
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.20.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0
```

I honestly feel like Terraform doesn't give very useful feedback on errors. Something similar to a traceback would be nice, but all I'm getting is "Couldn't find resource," highlighting the "{" part of `"resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs" {`

Any ideas?

Comment: The error happens on the first creation of the resource? Maybe you first created the resource, then deleted manually using aws console, and try to use it again from terraform?

Comment: That's possible. How would I recover from that?

Comment: If possible, you could maybe [rm](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm) the `aws_launch_configuration.ecs` from the state file.

Comment: It's not created yet: `No matching objects found. To view the available instances, use "terraform state list". Please modify the address to reference a specific instance.`

Comment: @Audiopolis, "I honestly feel like Terraform doesn't give very useful feedback on errors. Something similar to a traceback would be nice" - have you tried to adjust the logging level? E.g. as described here: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020022

Comment: I just did and realized it was a Bad Request response, probably related to the image_id value. Investigating. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was experimenting the same problem. I could solve it changing the AMI. In my case that solve everything. The error it does not specify that, but was enough to apply succesfully the resource.

By setting the `TF_LOG` environment variable to "DEBUG", you can see that AWS returns a Bad Request when trying to describe the specified AMI. Thanks to @qaziqarta for this tip.

Comment: I'm not sure which AMI I'm supposed to change. There's no AMI associated with my launch configuration. Do you mean the `aws_iam_role` associated with it through the `aws_iam_instance_profile`? In what way did you change it, if so?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Apologies to @user19642959. Being a noob, I read and understood "AMI" as "IAM" and so didn't understand what you meant. Changing the AMI to a valid one did indeed solve the problem.

Comment: I had a perfectly good terraform config. Then I tried to run it in another region. Sure enough the AMI would not exist there. I still have not tried with a new AMI, but this is a very good answer.

Comment: Yup. That worked. I would imagine such an error could occur when any resource that is region dependent shows up.

Answer (score 5):

Not an actual answer, but you can try to [adjust the logging level](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020022) to see if it will give you some clues:

```
export TF_LOG="DEBUG"
export TF_LOG_PATH="tmp/terraform.log"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out well showing the actual error message `DEBUG: Validate Response ec2/DescribeImages failed, attempt 0/25, error InvalidAMIID.NotFound: The image id '[ami-0cbea92f2377277a4]' does not exist` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly means your configuration cannot find the specified AMI. Validate if the AMI you are using exists in that region.